# ListPlot labeled points is extremely slow

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica 11

Compare below two timings

```
Table[AbsoluteTiming[ListPlot[RandomReal[1., {n, 2}]]][[1]], {n, 1, 
  200, 20}]
(*{0.0922182, 0.0868473, 0.0458226, 0.0350156, 0.0440754, 0.0346732, \
0.0368516, 0.0397308, 0.0528617, 0.0459663}*)
```

and

```
Table[AbsoluteTiming[
   ListPlot[Thread[RandomReal[1., {n, 2}] -> Range[n]]]][[1]], {n, 1, 
  200, 20}]
(*{0.445452, 0.621644, 1.20737, 2.16653, 3.06852, 7.26112, 12.347, \
17.6615, 23.6164, 29.5285}*)
```

Why plotting labeled points is so slow? Is there workaround?

---

**update**

Thanks to  rcollyer. The slowness is due to auto position algorithm gone crazy when number of points get larger.

A workaround is to specify label position explicitly, for example

```
Table[AbsoluteTiming[
   ListPlot[
    Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]], Below] & /@ 
     Thread[RandomReal[1., {n, 2}] -> Range[n]]]][[1]], {n, 1, 200, 
  20}]
(*{0.201465, 0.359929, 0.470717, 0.415873, 0.556001, 0.644012, \
0.707094, 0.945657, 0.874655, 1.12489}*)
```

Comment: `ListPlot` without labels is relatively straightforward to do, but adding labels and attempting to have them not overlap each other, is not. In fact, it is probably NP Hard. So, what you're seeing is the effects of the positioning algorithm go crazy because it can't comply.

Comment: @rcollyer I thought it maybe a bug. But your comment makes sense : )

Comment: ehm, is `Labeled` supposed to be in the second example? Otherwise comparing the two doesn't show us that `Labeled` is slow...

Comment: @C.E. because `coordinate->label` is dealt by `ListPlot` as labeled point. So I thought they are equivalent

Comment: @matheorem Ah... I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @C.E. You are welcome : )

Comment: @rcollyer Might I trouble you to post that as an Answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry got side tracked. Will post one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned above, the problem is in positioning the labels. Without the labels present, `ListPlot` does not have to do much but parse the data and determine appropriate `PlotRange`. The addition of labels, though, adds a conundrum: how do we place the labels in a pleasing manner with minimal overlap? This is not straightforward, and as the number of labeled points increases, it becomes even harder to accomplish. As you pointed out, the simplest method is to bypass the automatic placement algorithm, e.g (borrowing your code shamelessly)

```
Table[First@AbsoluteTiming@
   ListPlot[Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]], Below] & /@ 
     Thread[RandomReal[1., {n, 2}] -> Range[n]]]
  , {n, 1, 200, 20}
]
(*{0.201465, 0.359929, 0.470717, 0.415873, 0.556001, 0.644012, 
 0.707094, 0.945657, 0.874655, 1.12489}*)
```

The key thing to note here is that while it scales much better than the automatic algorithm, it does take quite a bit of extra time relative to no labels. So, after a certain point, you should look at only labeling specific points.